# I want to add and view players to certain team and view them depending on the team id in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am not sure how to move forward with this. I want to send the team_id through the URL and it submits like this
http://eurocup.test:8000/player?1
I want to take the number i.e. 1 and input the player name in that id so that I can retrieve the players of the specific team.

I have also done the relationships like team has many players and players belongs to team.

My players controller is as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Player;
use App\Models\Team;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Players\CreatePlayersRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Players\UpdatePlayersRequest;

class PlayersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Team $team)
    {   
        return view('players.index')->with('team', $team)->with('players', Player::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {   
        return view('players.create')->with('teams', Team::all());
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(CreatePlayersRequest $request)
    {

        Player::create([
            'playerName' => $request->playerName,
            'team' => $request->team
            
        ]);
        

        session()->flash('Success', 'Player Added Successfully.');
        return redirect(route('player.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Player $player)
    {
        return view('players.create')->with('player', $player)->with('teams', $team);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdatePlayersRequest $request,Player $player)
    {
         $player->update([
        'playerName' => $request->playerName
    ]); 
        session()->flash('success', 'Player Name Updated Successfully.');
        return redirect(route('player.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Player $player)
    {
        $player->delete();
        session()->flash('success', 'Player Deleted Successfully.');
        return redirect(route('player.index'));
    }
}
```

blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="card card-default">
    <div class="card-header">
        @if(isset($team))
        <a href="{{ route('player.create') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right">Add Players</a> {{ isset($team) ?  'Team and Players' : 'Players' }}
        {{$team->name}}
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th> Name </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th></thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($players as $player)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$player->playerName}}</td>
                        <td>{{$player->team_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$team->id}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
        </div>
    </div>
     @include ('partials.error')
    <div class="card card-default">
        <div class="card-header">
            Add Player
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{ route('player.store'),$team->id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @if(isset($player))
                @method('PUT')
                @endif
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="playerName" > Player Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="playerName" id="playerName" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="team">Team</label>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> {{ isset($player) ? 'Update Player' : 'Add Player' }}</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
    <form action="" method="POST" id="deletePlayerForm">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Player</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="text-center text-bold">Are you sure want to delete this? </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No, Go back</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    @section('scripts')
    <script>
    function handleDelete(id) {
    var form = document.getElementById('deletePlayerForm')
    form.action = '/player/' + id
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show')
    }
    </script>
    @endsection
```

route

```
Route::resource('player', 'App\Http\Controllers\PlayersController');
```

What I really want to do is like in PHP

```
<a href="viewcase.php?id= '.$row['id'].' " class = "btn btn-primary"> View Cases </a>
```

you provide the row id

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

and get it like this

So that I can use the id to input players to that id in order to view unique players of each team.

Comment: Your questions makes us confused what you mean, please re-write your question.

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez he wants to do `http://eurocup.test:8000/player/1` instead of `http://eurocup.test:8000/player?1`... it as simple as editing the `form` at the bottom.

Comment: @AnkitS you can pass data to your `view` with a simple `with` and then put an array inside, do not do `->with(...)->with(...)->with(...)`, and if you want to send info for only 1 request (`flash`), do `redirect(...)->with(...)`, don't do `session()->flash(...)` (internally it does `$this->session->flash(...)`, but do it the Laravel way....

Comment: I see, that's quit simple to do but that's until the question improved. Also you may add me guys for more collaboration and I can help you anytime with your problem. 

 Add me at skype: https://join.skype.com/invite/abZvk3YaQjgx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the team along with the players, then you may do this.

http://eurocup.test:8000/players?team_id=1

```
class PlayersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Team $team)
    {   
         

        $team = Team::where('id', request()->input('team_id'))->with('players')->first();


        return view('players.index')->with(['team' => $team, 'players' => $team->players]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can pass data to the view with a simple `with`, use an array `with(['team' => $team, 'players'....])`, do not do `->with(...)->with(...)->with(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @matiaslauriti, I'll improve my answer.

Comment: @matiaslauriti add me on skype: jesus.erwin.suarez143

Comment: Trying to get property 'players' of non-object
It shows the following error

Comment: I think it is because in my teams table there is no column for players but in my players table there is team_id column. So $team->player cannot be found